# Does AWS Greengrass lambda support for .Net core runtime?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

Is there any way to use .Net core as lambda runtime to deploy on edge device?
As per AWS documentation,SDK available only in Java , Node JS , Python and C.
I want to deploy .Net core package on my edge device through AWS greenGrass group which can communicate with devices and other lambda function locally in both online and offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, version 3.1 and 2.1:

[image]

Also, you can create your own custom Runtime:

[net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/)

[net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-aws-lambda-supports-for-net-core-3-1/)